# Impossible to run external javascript from HTML/EJS file

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, content-security-policy

I am attempting to run javascript in an external file within a HTML/EJS page.  Code is as follows:

```
<body onload="initialize()">

//HTML content

  <script src="/public/js/gallery.js"</script>

</body>
```

The "initialize()" function is located within the "gallery.js" file.  The problem is that I am continuously getting an error which reads:

"Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-tPMkUWbNPBXQQ3rlbFhILb35szR89eQb3Z41bzLr+wQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

I have tried a number of attempted fixes in my "head" tag on the page.  These include "<meta Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">", "Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'", and "meta http-equiv="content-security-policy content=script-src"...

This is maddening...I have spent hours trying to correct this.  Can somebody PLEASE offer some explanation on what the problem is...???  I thank you in advance.  Regards.

The 'gallery.js' file reads as follows:

```
addEventListener("load", initialize);

function initialize() {

//do stuff  

}
```

Comment: That script tag is broken. The opening tag is missing its closing >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving this by disabling the CSP rule that bans inline scripts is not a good idea. Inline scripts are a prime vector for XSS attacks.

Instead, remove the inline script and put equivalent  functionality in the `.js` file itself.

Remove `onload="initialize()"` from the HTML.

Add `addEventListener("load", initialize)` to the JS.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I added a synopsis of the '.js' file.  I am still getting the same error.  I have removed the 'onload' in the 'body' tag...does it matter where I call the '.js' script...should it be in the 'head' tag instead?

Comment: Since you said EJS; you *are* loading this from a web server and not a local file, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I moved my call of the '.js' script to the head tag of the .ejs file.  That seemed to solve the error...however another problem has been revealed, it seems my passed variables from the server are unable to be read by the external '.js' file.  For example when I render the page from the server I pass an array, as such "res.render('pages/_gallery', {pix_list: _gallery});".  However my variable (for example "<%= pix_list.length %>") is not read in the attached '.js' file...I probably need to post that as a separate question...

Comment: Store data like that in a `data-*` attribute and then read it from the JS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sorry I do not understand what context that should be formed.  I am looking at the "https://ejs.co/" webpage and do not see a tag that uses a "*" like that.  It seems I could read ejs variables passed from the server before using inline script on the .ejs page...however it seems to not pass to the external .js file...?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: You make a request to `/X` and the server processes it by injecting some variables into an EJS program and outputting the response. The response includes `<script src="/public/js/gallery.js">` so the browser makes a completely seperate request to `/public/js/gallery.js` which **isn't** handled by injecting variables into an EJS template so of course you can't use EJS code inside it. Put the data in the HTML document using `data-*` then read it from the DOM in your JS.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will have to study those links that you had attached to try to figure this out.  I appreciate the help very much.  Regards.

Comment: OK after reviewing those link(s) it seems I can assign the passed variable to a 'data' attribute such as "data-parent=<%= pix_list.length %>" and then I should be able to read those values in the '.js' file using a "document.querySelector('#some_ID')" and "data = article.dataset;"...I think I understand...thanks again.